# Why does Dykstra's projection algorithm work?

Tags: algorithms, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, projection

<sub>**Not** to be confused with [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)!</sub>

---

Can anyone help me understand why [Dykstra's projection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dykstra%27s_projection_algorithm)  works, at-least in $\mathbb{R}^d$ ? I looked at his paper$^\dagger$ and can read what the algorithm says ( not the proof yet ) but cant get my head around why it would work. Does anyone have a video or figure which helps explain this? The image on wikipedia does show the convergence but doesn't give me a feel as to whats going on...

---

<sub>$\dagger$ James P. Boyle, Richard L. Dykstra, [A method for finding projections onto the intersection of convex sets in Hilbert spaces](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-9940-7_3), Advances in Order Restricted Statistical Inference, Springer, 1986.</sub>

Comment: I think that Dykstra’s method for projecting onto $A \cap B$, where $A$ and $B$ are closed convex sets, can be interpreted as using the Douglas-Rachford method to minimize $I_A(x) + I_B(x) + \frac12 \| x - \hat x \|_2^2$. Here $I_A$ and $I_B$ are the convex indicator functions of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @littleO yes writing it as $_()+_()+(1/2)‖−̂ ‖2^2_2 $ is just a reformulation of the problem.

Comment: @littleO Do you know of an accessible reference for Douglas-Rachford?

Comment: Boyd’s manuscript on Proximal Algorithms is worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C_1,\ldots,C_n$ be nonempty closed convex subsets of $X$.
Set $Y := X^n$ and $A\colon X\to Y \colon x\mapsto (x,x,\ldots,x)$.

Set $C := C_1\cap \cdots \cap C_n\subset X$ and set
$S := C_1\times\cdots \times C_n \subseteq Y$.
Finally, let $z\in X$.

Then the projection of $z$ onto $C$ is the unique solution to
the optimization problem:

$$\min_{x\in X} \tfrac{1}{2}\|x-z\|^2 + \iota_{S}(Ax),$$
where $\iota_S$ is the indicator function of $S$.

Now set $f := x\mapsto \tfrac{1}{2}\|x-z\|^2$ and
$g := \iota_S$. Then the above problem can be written as

$$\min_{x\in X} f(x) + g(Ax).$$

Next, consider the Fenchel dual of the last problem which is

$$\min_{y\in Y} f^*(-A^*y) + g^*(y).$$

Note that this dual lives in $Y=X^n$. Now if you apply **cyclic
descent** to this dual problem, then you obtain Dykstra's algorithm.
For more details, see the paper by Gaffke-Mathar on the wikipedia page you linked to.

Finally, to @littleO : Dykstra $\neq$ Douglas-Rachford. The opposite was claimed in some paper by Boyd and quashed in Bauschke and Koch's paper "Projection methods: Swiss Army knives for solving feasibility and best approximation problems with halfspaces", in *Infinite Products and Their Applications*, pp. 1-40, AMS, 2015.

Relevant references are the books by Bauschke and Combettes, and by Beck.

Comment: Hmm, the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.4506.pdf) you mentioned states (in footnote 7 on p. 22) that "This statement appears to be at least ambiguous because the crucial starting points are not specified." Here is the [paper of Boyd and Parikh](https://stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf) for reference (see p. 34). Does this mean that the statement in Boyd and Parikh is incomplete rather than wrong? It sounds like with suitable starting points for ADMM, Dykstra's algorithm is a special case of ADMM. I haven't checked the details though.

Comment: I think no. I would be surprised if it is true (unless you start in the intersection).